# Can't suppress nodes in BizTalk mapping

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

Afternoon all,
I'm learning BizTalk and am stuck on this problem.

There's a choice group with either telephone or address.
I can get the some of the address fields to be suppressed when outputting the telephone.
To make things simpler I'll just discuss the "CityName" field .

I've tried the following:

- Mapped the "City" (text) node in the input file to "CityName" in the output. Connected an *Exists* logical functoid to the "Address1" node in the input node and the "CityName" in the output. I always get a city name with text filled in.
- Mapped the "City" node in the input file and the *Exists* logical functoid to a *Value Mapper* functoid. Connected the *Value Mapper* functoid to the CityName in the output. I get a city name in the address node (Correct) and an empty node in the telephone node (Incorrect).
- Mapped the "City" node in the input file and the Exists logical functoid to a *Value Mapper (Flattening)* functoid. Connected the *Value Mapper (Flattening)* functoid to the CityName in the output. I get a city name in the address node (Correct) and an empty node in the telephone node (Incorrect).

I thought one of the last two should have worked but both give an empty node instead of a suppressed node. The empty nodes have no attributes.

The CityName node is described by this schema type:

```
<xsd:complexType name="NameType">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:attribute name="languageID" type="xsd:language" use="optional">
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="sequence" type="IntegerNumericType">
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="sequenceName" type="StringType" />
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="IntegerNumericType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer" />
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="StringType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string" />
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Is there something in the type definition that's forcing an empty node to be created?

Thanks

EDIT: Below is the incorrect output. The second and third Communication nodes have
an Address Child node and should not.

I have a *looping functoid* on the phone numbers and the first address line in a flat input schema. That produces the three Communications nodes. I'm using a *Logical Existance* functoid on the address line to suppress the phone info in the first node. I have a *Logical Not* functoid on the output of that which is tied directly to the Address node in the output schema. I thought that should turn off the entire address node but it doesn't.

I tried adding a *Value Mapping* functoid connected to the *Logical Existance* functoid to the City Name and Postal code elements and that makes them empty, but they just will not go away. ARG!

I checked and the fields are all set to zero MinOccurs and I don't believe they're assigned a default value.

```
<ns0:Communication>
    <ns0:Address>
        <ns0:AddressLine sequence="1">1234 My St</ns0:AddressLine>
        <ns0:AddressLine sequence="2">Apt. 2</ns0:AddressLine>
        <ns0:CityName>Kansas City</ns0:CityName>
        <ns0:CountrySubDivisionCode name="State">MO</ns0:CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <ns0:CountrySubDivisionCode name="County">Jackson</ns0:CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <ns0:CountryCode>US</ns0:CountryCode>
        <ns0:PostalCode>64099</ns0:PostalCode>
    </ns0:Address>
</ns0:Communication>
<ns0:Communication sequence="1">
    <ns0:ChannelCode>Telephone</ns0:ChannelCode>
    <ns0:UseCode>Personal</ns0:UseCode>
    <ns0:DialNumber>1234567890</ns0:DialNumber>
    <ns0:Address>
        <ns0:CityName />
        <ns0:CountryCode />
        <ns0:PostalCode>64099</ns0:PostalCode>
    </ns0:Address>
</ns0:Communication>
<ns0:Communication sequence="2">
    <ns0:ChannelCode>Telephone</ns0:ChannelCode>
    <ns0:UseCode>Business</ns0:UseCode>
    <ns0:DialNumber>0987654321</ns0:DialNumber>
    <ns0:Address>
        <ns0:CityName />
        <ns0:CountryCode />
        <ns0:PostalCode>64099</ns0:PostalCode>
    </ns0:Address>
</ns0:Communication>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help to have sample input and output xml snippets. Without that, I can guess at the xml structures. If they look something like this, then the below mapping should work fine:

[image: simple biztalk map of address and phone fields]

Do your schemas look like that? The output produced by such a map is valid IF the `<Choice>` in the destination schema is set to `Max Occurs = unbounded`. If that's not the case, and if you can only have one Contact output, then you would have to only output the Phone if the Address is not there, like this:

[image]

Of course, that seems a bit silly, since one would expect to have both an Address and a Phone in the source xml, and the destination xml prevents you from having both.

If none of these scenarios matches up with yours, then please edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: Edited the original question to include the details you asked about. Thanks for the help BTW

Answer (score 0):

The min & max occurrences on the schema defaults to 1. The mapper looks at that when generating the XSLT. Try setting Min Occur to 0.

Comment: Didn't help. Set all of it to minOccurs 0.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this issue is to use [xsl directly](http://alamnaushad.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/biztalk-map-using-custom-xslt/) instead of the built in mapper.

With xsl you can control when and how values are selected. That's very difficult
when using multiple looping functoids.